# Does an enchantment ability that gives -1/-1 to opponent creatures resolve before other abilities can be used on a 1/1 entering the battlefield

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I control an [Ethereal Absolution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEthereal%20Absolution%5d) that gives all opponents creatures -1/-1.  On my opponents turn he sacrifices a creature to create two 1/1 white token spirits.  He then wants to sacrifice these using an ability on another card (Teysa Orzhov Scion).

My question is does the enchantment resolve first and remove the 1/1 tokens, e.g. as completion of them entering the battle field, and, before his ability can be triggered, or as he is the active player he gets to decide the order?

Comment: Could you give us the name of the enchantment please? It might matter for the answer.

Comment: @Hackworth, edited question t put card in question in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Your opponent cannot sacrifice them before they die. The -1/-1 ability is a *static* ability. It is always in effect, does not use the stack, and will kill off all */1 creatures before anyone can interact with them.**

A *static ability* such as "Creatures your opponents control get -1/-1." is always in effect:

> 604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.

That means creatures this applies to enter the battlefield with the -1/-1 effect. The game never sees a 1/1 creature, it enters as a 0/0. As soon as the spell or effect that put that creature on the battlefield has resolved, the game checks for *state-based actions* (A set of rules that is checked almost all the time), because the active player would gain *priority* (the right to take actions).

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
>
> 116.5. Each time a player would get priority, the game first performs all applicable state-based actions as a single event (see rule 704, “State-Based Actions”),[..]
>
> 704.5. The state-based actions are as follows:
>
> 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.

Comment: This will cause creatures that have abilities that trigger when other creatures die to still fire right?

Comment: Yes it does, it's a regular creature death.

Comment: @JoeW if you want you can search for the modern deck that uses dredgevine and bridge from below to see this "interaction".